# RReliefF feature selection in Python

Tags: feature-selection

Is there a Python package available that has RReliefF feature selection for regression targets implemented?

*Theoretical and Empirical Analysis of ReliefF and RReliefF*

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1025667309714

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an implementation from `sklearn-relief` package:

https://gitlab.com/qafir/sklearn-relief

Comment: https://epistasislab.github.io/scikit-rebate/using/  I found another implementation.

Comment: Does scikit-rebate support continuous outcomes as in regression problem?